# Eclipse Neon fails to install

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I have just downloaded Eclipse neon 64bit. I've already got jdk8, jre8 installed and configured, I do not have any other versions of Eclipse installed.

When I install eclipse it simply fails. Any idea? all I'm doing is installing the software!

> [2017-01-11 15:05:45] Mirrored 1 artifacts from http://mirror.tspu.ru/eclipse/releases/neon/201612211000/ at 13kb/s
>   [2017-01-11 15:05:45] Mirrored 1 artifacts from http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/eclipse//releases/neon/201612211000/ at 0kb/s
>   [2017-01-11 15:05:45] Collected 1143 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000 in 50.093s
>   [2017-01-11 15:05:45] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
>   [2017-01-11 15:05:45] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1093)
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=E__DATA_Dev_Eclipse_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=0 No repository found containing: binary,epp.package.jee.executable.win32.win32.x86_64,4.6.2.20161208-0625
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=0 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature,4.6.2.20161208-0625
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=0 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.jee,4.6.2.20161208-0625
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=0 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature,4.6.2.20161208-0625

Comment: hmm.

I ran the installer again, it took 5 seconds then said installed, the eclipse folder is tiny so it must be putting all the plugins elsewhere so I bet I've got a half dodgy copy installed now with plugins half completed and I'll never know what is working or not working until it's too late...

Comment: I'd recommend not to use the installer and download your desired package from [Eclipse Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) directly.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Oxygen.  I really wish they cut the crap with the installer. All these processes and repositories it tried to connect to is over-complicating things. The installer should just unpack and copy the files. Shouldn't be that hard to do surely.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, but I found out it was my firewall preventing the different mirrors from running. I temporarily shut it down and Eclipse installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download the zipped content of eclipse and run it directly. No need of installation.

64 Bit Eclispse Neon download link:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/2/eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32-x86_64.zip

Extract these files and run eclipse.exe

Other packages details are here :
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Answer (score 0):

make next:
[youuser@youmachine]$ sudo chown -R youuser:youuser  /usr/lib64/eclipse
   ..and try install neon again.